# Read and write from and to single Ms Access database from many applications simultaneously

Tags: c#, ms-access, jet

I've tested this and I can see is possible to have multiple opened `OleDbConnection`s from multiple applications (or same many instances of the same application) to the same Access database, and even have many `OleDbDataReader` opened at the same time.

But is this safe? Should I take any special care or will the `Jet` engine take care of everything? What would happen if I'm reading one data table while writing to the same table at the same time?

I just don't want to stumble upon gotchas or surprises later on.

Answer (score 2):

Access is generally not the engine for concurrent data activity.  Any reason why you would avoid MySQL or Oracle or other proper RDBMS?

Some reasons:

-You are not guaranteed a read consistent view.
-You get the strong possibility of updating an updated record without knowing.
-You may experience unresolvable locks
-You have no centralized transaction manager

Answer (score 1):

Access was not designed for concurrent usage. You should investigate using a different database. [Here's](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-limitations-of-ms-access.html) an excellent article on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

To directly response to your question `What would happen if I'm reading one data table while writing to the same table at the same time?`

Depends on the default `IsolationLevel`.  You can read about what Isolation Levels are and how to specify them at [Protecting Your Data Integrity with Transactions in ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971557.aspx).

But as others suggested, please use something else.  [SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) is fully featured and mostly free.  If you still want the ability to use a database without installing a server software I would even recommend [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) over Access.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience is, for 5 to 10 users (each one with 1 connection) with "not more data a user can enter by typing some input into a form", used in a local network, Access is ok as a backend. This article reflects my personal experience:

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4462

The real limits and the point where you should look for a "real" Client/Server database is heavily dependent of the details of your environment - if you want to know, you will have to run your own benchmarks.

Concerning the concurrent read/writes to a table: Access uses the byte-range locking capabilities of the underlying file system to deal with collisions (see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking for more information). This mechanism works on most modern file systems like NTFS, but does not scale well to many users.